# Problem with webscraping selector gadget and rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape data from https://3g.dxy.cn/newh5/view/pneumonia , using SelectorGadget and rvest

I successfully scrape some text in the page with the following code.

```
library(rvest)
url        <- 'https://3g.dxy.cn/newh5/view/pneumonia'
webpage    <- read_html(url)

TEXT_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.descText___Ui3tV')
TEXT      <- html_text(TEXT_html)
```

But when I try to select the table where the most important data (the number of people infected in the table) [see selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gy2k.png) using the following code

```
TABLE_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.areaBlock1___3V3UU p')
TABLE      <- html_text(TABLE_html)
```

the output is `"character 0"`

I guess it's because the data in the table can't be seen because they are refreshed via API, but I don't really know how to solve this

Anybody has an idea? thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this page, the data isn't retrieved seperately from an API. It is actually present in the html page you downloaded, but it is in JSON format inside a script tag and the reason why rvest can't read it is that the data is only added to the DOM by Javascript after the page loads. To get at the data you need to extract and parse the JSON:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tibble)
library(jsonlite)

data <- 'https://3g.dxy.cn/newh5/view/pneumonia'  %>%
        read_html()                               %>%
        html_node('#getAreaStat')                 %>%  # This is the tag containing the JSON 
        html_text()                               %>%  # Get the javascript from the node
        strsplit("(getAreaStat = )|(}catch)")     %>%  # Carve out the JSON
        unlist()                                  %>%  
        `[`(2)                                    %>%  # Unlist and extract the JSON
        fromJSON()                                     # Parse the JSON
```

Now `data` is a data frame containing all the information from the JSON. However, the last column of `data` is actually a list of city-level data frames. Since these all have the same column names they can be bound together with `rbind`. The final column can then be removed from `data` so you have a data frame of province-level data and another one of city-level data.

```r
city_data      <- as_tibble(do.call(rbind, data$cities))
province_data  <- as_tibble(data[, -8])
```

So `province_data` looks like a bit like this (the Chinese symbols haven't copied over but appear in the R console)

```
province_data
#> # A tibble: 33 x 7
#>    provinceName provinceShortNa~ confirmedCount suspectedCount curedCount deadCount
#>    <chr>        <chr>                     <int>          <int>      <int>     <int>
#>  1 ???       ??                       2714              0         52       100
#>  2 ???       ??                        207              0          4         0
#>  3 ???       ??                        173              0          3         0
#>  4 ???       ??                        168              0          0         1
#>  5 ???       ??                        143              0          0         0
#>  6 ???       ??                        132              0          0         0
#>  7 ???       ??                        106              0          0         0
#>  8 ???       ??                         95              0          0         0
#>  9 ???       ??                         91              0          2         1
#> 10 ???       ??                         90              0          0         0
#> # ... with 23 more rows, and 1 more variable: comment <chr>
```

and city_data looks like this (again, with cityName printed properly in the console).

```r
#> # A tibble: 329 x 5
#>    cityName confirmedCount suspectedCount curedCount deadCount
#>    <chr>             <int>          <int>      <int>     <int>
#>  1 ??               1590              0         47        85
#>  2 ??                213              0          2         4
#>  3 ??                173              0          0         1
#>  4 ??                114              0          0         3
#>  5 ??                 91              0          0         0
#>  6 ??                 71              0          1         2
#>  7 ??                 70              0          0         0
#>  8 ??                 70              0          0         0
#>  9 ??                 65              0          0         0
#> 10 ??                 57              0          0         0
#> # ... with 319 more rows
```

Comment: I was not familiar with JSON format and trying to crank out another way. This is good to know. If you do not mind, let me leave a similar version based on your script. `read_html("https://3g.dxy.cn/newh5/view/pneumonia") %>% html_node('#getAreaStat') %>% html_text() %>% gsub(pattern = "^.*getAreaStat = |\\}catch.*$", replacement = "") %>% fromJSON %>% unnest(cities, names_repair = "minimal")` I changed the way to get JSON data. I also changed the do.call part.

Comment: By the way, is that fromJSON() from the jsonlite package?

Comment: @jazzuro yes, it's jsonlite - I'll update my answer thanks

Comment: Thank you. For this table, the procedure is clear. What it's not clear is where you found the tag containing the JSON  `#getAreaStat`, and subsequently where you took the sintax for `strsplit("(getAreaStat = )|(}catch)")` and  ``[`(2)`  .

I wanted also to access the following table but I can't, due to these reasons.
Thank you for your time again

UPDATE: I opened `webpage` and found where you found #getAreaStat.. So I should be able to find also the other table. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @PaoloMontemurro if you press F12 in your browser you can see the HTML of the entire page, search it, copy it into a text editor and look for the section that you want.